# Android Google Plus SDK: sign in window not displaying

Tags: android, api, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

When a user never logged in Google + with my app or did a revoke and want to login again, the following window is displayed once he clicked on the login button:

[image: Google Plus initial login window]

My problem is the following:

- if I copy paste the activity SigninActivity of the Google Sample project in my project, everything works well : the window is displayed when I click on the connect button
- if I copy paste the Google code in my main activity (I think I forgot nothing and did it well) in order to have the connect button and connection process directly in my activity, this window is no more displayed...

To be accurate, as I have 2 Gmail accounts on my phone, what happens is:

- execution of the command  mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
  REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
- a window asks with which Gmail account I want to connect
- I choose a Gmail account

and...here is the moment when I should see the Google Plus connection window but I don't !

Any idea ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The way to access that particular screen are:

1) Never logged in (as you mentioned)
2) Revoke and then login (as you mentioned)

and

3) getSettingsIntent()  [getSettingsIntent() at Google Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#getSettingsIntent%28%29)

The difference between 3) and the other two is that the user is given an overview of current settings which can be changed for your application, and is not show the same exact screen for initial login.  (They are shown "Sign out" and "Sharing settings" options from which they  can change the different visibilities/information access)

```
public void sendTestIntent() {
        Intent i = mHelper.getGamesClient().getSettingsIntent();
        startActivityForResult(i, RC_SETTINGS);
    }
```